# Body parser use bodyParser middleware from another middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, body-parser

So, I am working on this express app in which all routes have limited body size, except if you are admin, since admin needs unlimited body size for several routes. I have limitBodySize middleware and I am using it like this: `app.use(middleware.limitBodySize)`

But in the end my body is not parsed and everything is undefined.

```
limitBodySize: (req, res, next) => {
  let admin = true; // removed extra steps for simplicity

  if (admin) {
    bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })(req, res, () => {
      console.log(req.body) // logs undefined
      bodyParser.json()(req, res, () => {
        console.log(req.body) // logs undefined
        next(); // in next route, console.log(req.body) logs undefined
      });
    });
  } else {
    bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: '1kb' })(req, res, () => {
      bodyParser.json({ limit: '1kb' })(req, res, () => {
        next();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

How can I solve this, with only one middleware, not by passing bodyParser middlewares to every route or router separetly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should generate the `bodyParser` middleware outside your custom conditional middleware since it's meant to be reusable.

You're also not checking for errors; it's possible that your `bodyParser` middleware is providing an error to the anonymous callbacks you've passed as the `next` parameter to them, so handle the errors properly. One of the simplest ways to do this is to promisify each of the middleware using the [`util`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) module since you're already chaining them anyway.

My suspicion is that your request body might be JSON, and the `urlencoded` middleware is attempting to parse it unsuccessfully. At this point, `bodyParser` has consumed the body stream, so the `json` middleware will probably fail as well. Since you're ignoring both errors, you won't know for sure what the next fix is until you try this:

```
const { promisify } = require('util')
const json = promisify(bodyParser.json())
const limitedJson = promisify(bodyParser.json({ limit: '1kb' }))
const urlencoded = promisify(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
const limitedUrlencoded = promisify(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: '1kb' }))

...

limitBodySize: (req, res, next) => {
  ...

  if (admin) {
    urlencoded(req, res).then(
      () => json(req, res)
    ).then(
      () => next(),
      next
    )
  } else {
    limitedUrlencoded(req, res).then(
      () => limitedJson(req, res)
    ).then(
      () => next(),
      next
    )
  }
}
```

This will pass any errors to the express framework using the `onRejected` parameter of `.then()`

Using ECMAScript 2017's `async` and `await` syntax, you can make it a little easier to read:

```
limitBodySize: async (req, res, next) => {
  ...

  try {
    if (admin) {
      await urlencoded(req, res)
      await json(req, res)
    } else {
      await limitedUrlencoded(req, res)
      await limitedJson(req, res)
    }

    next()
  } catch (error) {
    // if error occurs here, you probably need to figure out what your next issue is
    next(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code, and got understanding of an error I was facing, first of all, default bodyParser limit is 100kb, which I was surpasing with my requests, and second problem was the fact that I was sending files, which returned too many parameters error, so I increased parameterLimit, and now catch does not give any error, but body is deformed.

Comment: It looks like this, any idea why? { '------WebKitFormBoundaryS8lANGAVimhAaXy2\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name':
   '"name"\r\n\r\nname,\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryS8lANGAVimhAaXy2\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="description"\r\n\r\ndescription,\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryS8lANGAVimhAaXy2\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="nutritionalInfo"\r\n\r\nnutritionalInfo,\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryS8lANGAVimhAaXy2\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="price"\r\n\r\nprice\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryS8lANGAVimhAaXy2--\r\n' }

Comment: And this is what I am using now: const json = promisify(bodyParser.json({ limit: '100mb' }));
const limitedJson = promisify(bodyParser.json({ limit: '1kb' }));
const urlencoded = promisify(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: '100mb', parameterLimit: 1000000 }));
const limitedUrlencoded = promisify(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: '1kb' }));

Comment: Omg, problem is that I am trying to send multipart form, that said, I just need module to handle multipart form, that is why your and my examples won't work... Thanks anyways